# Wi-Fi Router with only Wi-Fi network creating

Tags: networking, wifi, linksys, repeater

I have Linksys WRT-160NL Wi-Fi router with DD-WRT firmware on it. The problem is setting traffic shaping for IPs in router's Wi-Fi network. The only needed thing is to limit up/down speed to (say) 1Mb per PC.

As DD-WRT and native firmware do not have their own traffic shaping opportunity, i have decided to put a program router/pc before router with squid/kerio on it, which has this opportunity. It also acts as DHCP-server. But the router doesn't pass these IPs to computers when router acts in "Access Point" mode.

The problem is: is there any router mode when it just organises Wi-Fi network and just passes IP addresses from DHCP-server to computers connected to this Wi-Fi network? (like wi-fi switch)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saying DD-WRT does not have traffic shaping capabilities ? It does have some ([http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service]). If this is not sufficient you can use the standard linux QoS tool (tc), there is good documentation at [http://lartc.org].

DD-WRT in Access Point mode should allow wireless clients to get a DHCP answer from a wired server. The detailed procedure is here: [http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point]. If it does not work you may want to use a packet sniffer on the DHCP server to check if the requests do arrive to the server.